# Azure Terraform cosmos module. Provision Dynamic Database and Containers mapping

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am a bit struggling in this code as i cannot find a clear way to map resources. Here is what i mean:

I have a azure terraform module to provision a cosmos db. The basic configuration and deployment, such as provision an account + database + containers works just fine. But i wanted to make this module a bit more dynamic. Which mean i can provision as many databases i want and allocate to each database the correct containers.

So far this is my broken code in the module:

Variables.tf

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure resource group."
  type        = string
}

variable "cosmosdb_account_name" {
  description = "The name of the Cosmos DB account."
  type        = string
}

variable "locations" {
  description = "location where to deploy the infra."
  type        = string
}

variable "databases" {
  description = "A map of Cosmos DB databases, each with its associated containers."
  type        = map(list(string))
}

variable "throughput" {
  description = "Throughput in Request Units (RU) for Cosmos DB containers."
  type        = number
  default     = 400
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "cosmosdb" {
  location            = var.locations
  name                = var.cosmosdb_account_name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  kind = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  enable_automatic_failover = false

  geo_location {
    failover_priority = 0
    location          = var.locations
  }
  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Session"
  }


}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database" "database" {
  for_each            = var.databases
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "container" {
  for_each = {
    for db, containers in var.databases : "${db}-${container}" => containers
  }

  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
  database_name       = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.database[each.key].name
  throughput          = var.throughput
  partition_key_path  = "/PartitionKey"
}
```

when i call this module for provisioning, like in this main.tf

```
module "campaign_stats_cosmos" {
  source                = "<Module-source>"
  version               = "0.0.25"
  resource_group_name = "my-resource-group"
  cosmosdb_account_name = "my-cosmosdb-account"
  locations = var.locations
  databases = {
    "database1" = ["container1", "container2"],
    "database2" = ["container3", "container4"],

  }
  throughput = 500
}
```

i get the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on .terraform\modules\campaign_stats_cosmos\main.tf line 29, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "container":
│   29:     for db, containers in var.databases : "${db}-${container}" => containers
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource     
│ name.
╵
```

want i would like, is to be able to map the containers to a specific databases but i cannot figure out how to achieve this as i keep getting error on mapping.

I hope someone can help me to address this issue as is driving me crazy

Comment: You are attempting to resolve the variable `container` with the normal implicit re-cast to a string within interpolation, but that variable appears to be undefined. It is unclear what your intention is for the resolved value of `container` to be within the string, but I would speculate you want to do a nested `for` expression for each element of the `containers`. Please clarify your intention here so we can assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried Provisioning the cosmos module by Provision Dynamic Database and Containers mapping using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully using locals.

The error you're encountering is due to incorrect usage of `for_each` in the `azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container` resource block. The error occurs because the expression `"${db}-${container}"` is not correctly formed and Terraform is unable to understand the reference to `container`.

To achieve this tried to build a flat map outside the resource and then use it in the `for_each`. This can be achieved by iterating through each database and its containers and creating a map where each key is a unique identifier composed of the database name and the container name. We will use a single `for` loop instead of a nested loop to avoid the complexity.

**My Terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}




resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "cosmosdb" {
  name                = var.cosmosdb_account_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  enable_automatic_failover = false

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Session"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database" "database" {
  for_each            = var.databases
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
}

locals {
  db_container_pairs = merge([
    for db, containers in var.databases : {
      for container in containers : "${db}-${container}" => {
        database_name = db
        container_name = container
      }
    }
  ]...)
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "container" {
  for_each = local.db_container_pairs

  name                = each.value.container_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
  database_name       = each.value.database_name
  throughput          = var.throughput
  partition_key_path  = "/PartitionKey"
}

output "cosmosdb_account_id" {
  value = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.id
}
```

##### variable.tf

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure resource group."
  type        = string
}

variable "cosmosdb_account_name" {
  description = "The name of the Cosmos DB account."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region where to deploy the infrastructure."
  type        = string
}

variable "databases" {
  description = "A map of Cosmos DB databases, each with its associated containers."
  type        = map(list(string))
}

variable "throughput" {
  description = "Throughput in Request Units (RU) for Cosmos DB containers."
  type        = number
  default     = 400
}
```

##### terraform.tfvars:

```
resource_group_name   = "demorg-vk1"
cosmosdb_account_name = "demovk-cosmosdb"
location              = "East US"
databases             = {
  "database1" = ["container1", "container2"],
  "database2" = ["container3", "container4"]
}
throughput            = 500
```

Here `locals` block now uses a single `for` loop within a `merge` function. This will flatten the structure into one map.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]